# How to use custom Analyzer in Elastic Search 1.5 for case Insensitive Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I like to use case Insensitive Search for Elastic Search 1.5. It does not allow type="keyword" and custom analyzer does not work. Do anyone knows how it works on Elastic Search 1.5

Comment: My Mapping this like :
{
  "settings": {
   "index":{
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "lowercase_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer":"keyword",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }
      }},
    "number_of_shards": 24,
    "number_of_replicas" : 0,
    "merge": {
      "scheduler": {
        "max_thread_count": 1
      }
    },
    "index.mapper.dynamic": false,
    "index.translog.flush_threshold_size" : "1gb"
  }},

Comment: inside mapping: Inside mapping:
"object": {
                      "properties": {
                        "EMAIL-ADDRESS": {
                          "analyzer": "lowercase_normalizer",
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "IP-ADDRESS": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },

Comment: inside mapping: 
                              "analyzer": "lowercase_normalizer",
                              "type": "string",
                              "fields": {
                                "es": {
                                  "doc_values": true,
                                  "analyzer": "lowercase_normalizer",
                                  "type": "string",
                                  "index": "not_analyzed"
                                }
                              },